# Надо ли объединить метки [wp] и [wordpress]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть 2 метки:

- [wp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp) (12 вопросов)
- [wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) (6 837 вопросов)

Не надо ли их объеденить?

Comment: Пусть будет так!